# Send values as a string to Access Database from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following query using C#

```
string sqlQuery = "select userinfo.badgenumber, userinfo.name, userinfo.ssn, checkinout.checktime, IIF(checkinout.checktype = 'O','Clock Out','Clock In') as checktype from checkinout, userinfo, machines where userinfo.userid = checkinout.userid";
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fromDate) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(toDate))
{
    sqlQuery += " and checkinout.checktime between #" + fromDate + " 00:00:00# and #" + toDate + " 23:59:59#";
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
{
    sqlQuery += " and userinfo.title in (" + title + ")";
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(empId))
{
    sqlQuery += " and checkinout.userid in (" + empId + ")";
}
```

When I debug it, it gives the following database query.

```
select userinfo.badgenumber, userinfo.name, userinfo.ssn, checkinout.checktime, IIF(checkinout.checktype = 'O','Clock Out','Clock In') as checktype from checkinout, userinfo, machines where userinfo.userid = checkinout.userid and checkinout.checktime between #12/28/2014 00:00:00# and #06/07/2015 23:59:59# and userinfo.title in (Manager,Sales) and checkinout.userid in (52,14,4) order by checkinout.userid, checkinout.checktime
```

Everything works fine, there is just a problem that I need single inverted commas around the strings. It should be ('Manager', 'Sales') but the query makes it (Manager, Sales) or if I use this

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
{
    sqlQuery += " and userinfo.title in (" + "'" + title + "'" + ")";
}
```

It gives me result like this ('Manager, Sales').

Comment: What `type` is `title`?

Comment: Title is a string datatype which has to be compared with string in database.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `title` is `Manager, Sales` and you want to get them as `'Manager', 'Sales'`, one way is combination of [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Join(v=vs.110).aspx) an [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.100).aspx) methods like;

```
var newTitle = string.Join(",", title.Split(',').Select(s => string.Format("'{0}'", s)));
// newTitle is 'Manager',' Sales'
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://csharppad.com/gist/972734557d42f19e944f)</kbd>.

Comment: @user2955299 But you said it is a `string`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't send them as strings with concatenated sql command.

Use parameterized query instead, that way you can avoid sql injection.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/268104-parameterizing-your-sql-queries-the-right-way-to-query-a-database/

Comment: Would be better as a comment?

Comment: You can concatenate them to a parameter value.